# What software was this designed in?

Tags: design, gears, cad

I'm trying to to teach myself to design gears for a hobby project, and I want to make a similar design. I typically use Autodesk inventor, but I was wondering if there was something better for this sort of thing. [image: gears with teeth missing]

This is from [this](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11204/is-there-a-mechanism-that-can-turn-circular-motion-into-alternating-circular-mot) question.

Comment: Autodesk for each component on its own. That image of meshed gears is likely from simulation software like Ansys after each component imported from Autodesk. Or maybe graphics software like Rhino. But Rhino is for animation, not design as far as I know.

Comment: @DKNguyen rhino is definitely a cad software

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is conjecture based on my experience with the 3D modeling program known as [OpenSCAD.](https://openscad.org/)

The colors of the components and placement are consistent with the program, as well as the background color. There is usually a set of axes visible with reference measurements, but those are easily disabled, allowing for a screen shot of this nature.

From the gallery option in the linked site:

[image: openscad sample image]